# Sanitizing data in PHP for excell xml

Tags: php, excel, html-escape-characters

I am currently using the "excel xml" PHP library (Marin Crnković, version 0.9) to write data from the database as an .xls file.  The problem is that the database contains data that is not legal, and this causes Microsoft Excel to give me errors when opening this file. (The document cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents)

Samples of bad data that is causing Excel display errors instead of opening the file:

> !(()&&!|*|*|
>
> '"()&%1prompt(918861)
>
> '&cat /etc/passwd&'
>
> '&dir&'
>
> "&cat /etc/passwd&"
>
> email&n921923=v950402

Is there a recommended function to sanitize the data before inserting the data into the Excel file?

Comment: Is it just the ampersand (&) that's causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to escape/encode the ampersands before using them for the Excel spreadsheets (as the new formats are XML-based). With PHP, you could perhaps try something like:

```
$value = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $value);
```